# Unwanted graphic offset

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I'm getting a small difference in horizontal alignment when using the two ways of placing an image as shown in my code below. I know it doesn't look like there's much point in what I've done, but this is just a minimal example showing the problem.

Anyone know why this happens? Or how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\newcommand{\scalebar}[1]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{#1}
}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!hptb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{image}
\caption{}
\label{normalImage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!hptb]
\centering
\scalebar{{image}}
\caption{}
\label{imageFromCommand}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shall I let egreg do the honors?  You need to put a % immediately after { (before \begin{tikzpicture}) and after \end{tikzpicture} or latex will add a space each time.

Comment: Hi John, I'm just commenting to say that your answer is right even though it looks a bit odd now that I've edited my original post. I realised that it wasn't anything to do with tikz and changed my example. It was because of my spacing though, thank you!

Comment: After you make the mistake a few dozen times...

Comment: Surely @JohnKormylo should be egreg in this case?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Please, go forth!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Close as dupe of one of the many others like this, or would you like to write up an answer?